# Grouping layers with groext - openlayer overlays menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, dictionary

i can't find out how to grup layers like in this example
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/controls.html
press the upper + button

as you can see there's a checkbox and two radio buttons

anyone knows a way to group layers so that they are displayed under the same group and it's possible to choose only one among them? (radio button)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try using GeoExt tree to do this, like this:
http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/tree.html

At this time OpenLayers does not support grouping beyond those mentioned by Brian above.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to display on the layers? Vectors can be [combined with styleMap](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/sandbox/camptocamp/maptypepanel/openlayers/examples/all-overlays.html?rev=10497). You might want to try is to make your layers base layers instead of overlays.

In OpenLayers there are 2 types of layers: base layers and overlays. When you add more than one of either of these to a map you get slightly different behaviour.

Base layers can only be displayed one at a time and a radio box is displayed to select which one is displayed. Check boxes are displayed for Overlays because any number of overlays can be displayed on top of a base layer. More information and examples are available on the [wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/BaseLayersAndOverlays).
 You